# Why objects are same in 2 different process of multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have next code:

**test.py:**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class A:
    def __action(self):
        print("another process:")
        print(id(self))

    def run(self):
        print("this process")
        print(id(self))
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.__action, daemon=True)
        p.start()

a = A()
print("main")
print(id(a))
a.run()
time.sleep(3)
```

It runs as next:

```
$ python3 test.py
main
140643898766000
this process
140643898766000
another process:
140643898766000
```

But from [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) next:

> As mentioned above, when doing concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as far as possible. This is particularly true when using multiple processes.
>
> However, if you really do need to use some shared data then multiprocessing provides a couple of ways of doing so.
>
> Shared memory
>
> Data can be stored in a shared memory map using Value or Array.

So it looks only with explicitly define `Value`/`Array` can the 2 processes have the same object. Then, why the `A object` in 2 different processes now have same id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're apparently running under some Linux-like OS, where multiprocessing uses `fork()` to create a worker process. Under `fork()`, the new process gets a copy-on-write clone of the parent process's address space. So, yes, objects inherited from the parent process after a `fork()` will have the same `id()`, but they're nevertheless entirely distinct objects. Addresses are virtual. The `self` in the main process lives in different *physical* memory than the `self` in the worker process. That they have the same virtual address in each process is just a consequence of how the OS implements `fork()`. Changes made to the object in one process will not be seen in the other.

On a system without `fork()` (chiefly Windows), or if you tell multiprocessing to use "spawn" instead of "fork", then it's very unlikely (although still possible) that `self` will retain the same virtual address.